# PHP code works locally but does not run correctly web server

Tags: php, localhost, web-hosting

I have a code from a client that runs on a local server. The index page shows background and forms but on the online server it only show background image and nothing else

Here is the index.php script:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

  <body id="login">
    <div class="container">

      <form id="login_form" class="form-signin" method="post">
        <h3 class="form-signin-heading"><i class="icon-lock"></i> Please Login</h3>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="usernmae" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
        <input type="password" class="input-block-level" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button name="login" class="btn btn-info" type="submit"><i class="icon-signin icon-"></i> Sign in</button>      
              </form>

<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#login_form").submit(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var formData = jQuery(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "login.php",
                        data: formData,
                        success: function(html){
                        if(html=='true')
                        {
                        $.jGrowl("Welcome to Thutoboswa Learning Management System", { header: 'Access Granted ðŸ˜€ #WearAMaskðŸ˜·' });
                        var delay = 2500;
                            setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'dashboard.php'  }, delay);  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        $.jGrowl("Please Check your username and Password", { header: 'Login Failed' });
                        }
                        }                       
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
            </script>
    </div>    
    
    <!-- /container -->
<?php include('script.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Mozila Firefox console shows these warnings:

```
This page uses the non standard property “zoom”. Consider using calc() in the relevant property values, or using “transform” along with “transform-origin: 0 0”. gobojangojss.co.bw

Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# insteadjquery-1.9.1.min.js:2:21

Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js:4:3946

downloadable font: bad search range (font-family: "TR Century Gothic" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: https://gobojangojss.co.bw/admin/bootstrap/css/TR%20Century%20Gothic.ttf

downloadable font: bad range shift (font-family: "TR Century Gothic" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: https://gobojangojss.co.bw/admin/bootstrap/css/TR%20Century%20Gothic.ttf

downloadable font: cmap: bad id_range_offset (font-family: "TR Century Gothic" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: https://gobojangojss.co.bw/admin/bootstrap/css/TR%20Century%20Gothic.ttf

Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://gobojangojss.co.bw/admin/vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
Source Map URL: jquery.min.map
```

Comment: There's no PHP code here except the two `include()` calls.

Comment: Check the server error log.

Comment: Open up your browser's developer console and reload the page. Check for any errors, such as missing files, in the Console and the Network tab.

Comment: No errors on server or on console

Answer (score 1):

Goood day, Ace.
Check please if you uploaded 2 files to server:

- header.php
- script.php

Another solution is to open Chrome Console. Press F12
And in NAME column you will see the PHP file that work with you Ajax query.
[image]

Click on this php file and see what POST parameters come back from server to you.
[image]

**update**

this string tell us that yourcode missing jquery.

```
Resource URL: https://gobojangojss.co.bw/admin/vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
```

Can you add this to functions,php file

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Comment: the files:
-header.php
-script.php
are uploaded on the server. 
Trying to follow the rest of your instructions.

Comment: Deal, Ace. If you need any help with PHP files, let me know please

Comment: I have updated the question. Chrome did not show any warnings but Firefox did. I added them to the question.